# Check for free domain names from a list of 5000 words

Tags: dns

I have a list of 5000 words I would like automatically to check which ones are free as xxxx.com domain. Is there a free service to do so instead of copy/pasting thousands of times in register.com

I am not searching for an automated solution to make profit of it. I need to buy a domain for myself.

Comment: If you have narrowed your list of possible domain names to 5000 *you're doing it wrong*.

Comment: FYI, if they're English dictionary words, I guarantee none of them are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are command-line tools like [`whois`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/whois/) that will do the check; I'd just write a shell script to do that

Comment: I think it's considered bad form to spam the whois service like that. Why not try to resolve domainname.com first and, if it doesn't resolve, check the whois? Probably faster that way anyway.

Comment: @Eli faster and more efficient.

Comment: @Eli Probably true, I don't know anybody that's ever needed to do such a ridiculous number of lookups

Answer (score 2):

You can also write a script to ping each of those then check who the response comes from.  Some DNS servers resolve unregistered domains to a parking page at a registrar.  If yours does that, just check for a mismatch with that IP address to find a domain that is unavailable.  A match means you should be able to register it.

Answer (score 0):

A number of whois/dig services are free, though ultimately the mitigating factor is going to be the throttling that you'll encounter with making requests. So long as you limit your queries to a number below the limit set by the provider, you'll do OK.